# spark standalone cluster not doing FIFO job submit

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark standalone cluster. As of now I have only 3 nodes, 1 master and 2 slave. my jobs are batch process so dont care how long it takes. When I submit 1 job, everything works fine. When I submit 5 jobs, the master assigns 1 node each to 2 driver programs out of the 5 jobs submitted and both the jobs have 0 cores left to do processing. I see the cores 0 for "running applications"

Comment: Have you tried specifying the number of cores to spark-submit ?

    `--executor-cores`

Comment: yes, that does not help

Comment: How are you submitting the jobs ? So no job gets run at all?